# coding and commenting to generate javadocs author name

Tags: java, javadoc

I am in the middle of making/generating javadocs. I need some help regarding the coding/commenting javadocs.

Why doesnt this or any class shows an auther name http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html      while in the source code. theres  @author Doug Lea or some other

This is just an example. It happens for every class.

How can I make the doc show the author name and more details?

code found in src.zip of hotspot oracle jdk:

package java.util.concurrent;
import java.util.Map;

```
/**
 * A {@link java.util.Map} providing additional atomic
 * <tt>putIfAbsent</tt>, <tt>remove</tt>, and <tt>replace</tt> methods.
 *
 * <p>Memory consistency effects: As with other concurrent
 * collections, actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a
 * {@code ConcurrentMap} as a key or value
 * <a href="package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility"><i>happen-before</i></a>
 * actions subsequent to the access or removal of that object from
 * the {@code ConcurrentMap} in another thread.
 *
 * <p>This interface is a member of the
 * <a href="{@docRoot}/../technotes/guides/collections/index.html">
 * Java Collections Framework</a>.
 *
 * @since 1.5
 * @author Doug Lea        <------------this
 * @param <K> the type of keys maintained by this map
 * @param <V> the type of mapped values
 */
public interface ConcurrentMap<K, V> extends Map<K, V> {
```

The api docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

```
Like Hashtable but unlike HashMap, this class does not allow null to be used as a key or value.

This class is a member of the Java Collections Framework.

Since:
1.5
See Also:
Serialized Form
```

No author here ^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the [documentation for javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#javadocoptions):

> -author
>
> Includes the @author text in the generated docs.

Comment: It does not. I have given a real example. the real docs in hotspot jdk has `@author` but that is NOT visible on the oracle site. I am having the same issue.

Comment: Did you pass the `-author` option when generating the javadoc? Have you clicked the link I gave in my answer?

Comment: oh. thats compulsory? I never passed -since option either but the docs have `Since 1.5` in them.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I was on the wrong side and -author was compulsory to add / enable / implement @author and display it in the html docs. Correct?

Comment: That's because some information is displayed by default (like public members, for example), whereas some are not (like private members, or authors, for example). It helps to read the documentation. Try with -author, and see if the author appears in the generated doc.

Comment: /me thumbs up @JB Nizet